# Any foundation to administrate an Android open source application?

Tags: android, open-source, project-management

Our open source application is quite popular, and we are many developers.
The app uses my Android Market account, and I shared the keys with a developer.

But if both of us disappear, the application's Market account will be lost, and all users trapped.
Giving the keys to all developers is not a solution either, for security reasons.

Is there a foundation (like in Mozilla Foundation or Apache Foundation) that could accept to hold our Android Market account and release new versions in accordance with their own guidelines and our community consensus?

There are quite a lot of [Open Source foundations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Open_source_project_foundations), but I could not find any that tackles this particular aspect of Android applications.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not about programming but laws, licensing and wills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [dead man's switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man's_switch) accomplishes this. Appoint long term / valued members of your community as successors in case the worst happens, make arrangements for the keys to be transferred to them.

You can also form your own foundation very easily, it need not be non-profit, nor is it required to pay any of its employees.

In my experience, umbrella organizations may not have the resources to stay in tune with the community to the degree needed to act quickly in case something happens. This is why [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_in_the_Public_Interest) has very little involvement with the organizations it serves, other than acting as a payment proxy.

You would do better to simply coordinate wills with the other developer, or set up something small that is intrinsic to your community.

Answer (score 2):

If you really are big enough that this is a problem (and, I suspect, if you're in the US), you might find that the [Software Freedom Conservancy](http://conservancy.softwarefreedom.org/) from the Software Freedom Law Center can help...